# Which is better one DLL for all or many DLLs?

Tags: dll, sharepoint-2007

We are working on a big portal that developed in SharePoint 2007 ..

We put custom code in Dlls .. some suggest to put all code for many components into one single dll instead of one dll for each component ..

My opinion is to put each component into a separate dll to affect memory in a good way ..

So, which is the better really .. to put all components into one single dll or have one dll for each component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create different assemblies for any reusable code. If you are not planning to reuse your code then its better to have the code in one assembly .. as it increases performance..

You should also check the following two threads

[Does .NET assembly size affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337144/does-net-assembly-size-affect-performance)
[.NET Cross-Assembly Performance Hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350313/net-cross-assembly-performance-hit)

Answer (score 2):

If your components are separately reusable, packaging them as separate assemblies / DLLs is sensible.  If they're a tangled mass of mutual dependencies, bundle them all into a single assembly or DLL.  You fail to tell us which is the case, so I don't think we can help any further until you do!-)

Comment: Then definitely use separate assemblies / DLLs for them.