# Performance hit of multiple assemblies

Tags: .net

I'm writing MVC support but that's not really important.

Right now, I have Business project, which contains infrastructure, application and domain layer with services.

I want to split this Business to, Application, Intrastructure, Domain, Services assemblies.

Is there any significant performance hit if i split my assembly into multiple assembly?

I do not really care about start up, i want to know if there is any difference when assemblies are already loaded

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does .NET assembly size affect performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337144/does-net-assembly-size-affect-performance), [.NET Cross-Assembly Performance Hit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350313/net-cross-assembly-performance-hit), [Is it ok to reference .Net assemblies liberally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472421/is-it-ok-to-reference-net-assemblies-liberally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any significant performance hit if i split my assembly into multiple assembly?

The more assemblies you have, the slower the startup time. But it won't be significant and not something you should be concerned with.